# Laravel Facebook Intregration get error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to integrating facebook sdk with my laravel app.but in my helper class get error

**Call to a member function getLoginUrl() on a non-object**

My helper class code:

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

```
class FacebookHelper
{

    private $helper;

    public function __construct(){

return FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(Config::get('facebook.app_id'), Config::get('facebook.app_secret'));

        $this->$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(url('login/fb/callback'));


    }
    public function getUrlLogin()
    {
        return $this->helper->getLoginUrl(Config::get('facebook.app_scope'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Constructor methods should never return anything.

Answer (score 0):

You do **return** in your constructor before you set the value of **$this->helper**, that's why you are getting the error.

Replace

```
public function __construct() {
  return FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(Config::get('facebook.app_id'), Config::get('facebook.app_secret'));
  $this->$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(url('login/fb/callback'));
}
```

with

```
public function __construct() {
  FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(Config::get('facebook.app_id'), Config::get('facebook.app_secret'));
  $this->$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(url('login/fb/callback'));
}
```